# Converting BSON data saved in file to Javascript object

Tags: javascript, bson

I'm trying to convert a BSON file generated by a python script into a Javascript object. I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/bson for the BSON package and using `XMLHttpRequest` to load the file.

In case it matters, this is my package-lock.json entry for `bson`.

```
        "bson": {
            "version": "4.0.4",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/bson/-/bson-4.0.4.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-Ioi3TD0/1V3aI8+hPfC56TetYmzfq2H07jJa9A1lKTxWsFtHtYdLMGMXjtGEg9v0f72NSM07diRQEUNYhLupIA==",
            "requires": {
                "buffer": "^5.1.0",
                "long": "^4.0.0"
            },
            "dependencies": {
                "buffer": {
                    "version": "5.6.0",
                    "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/buffer/-/buffer-5.6.0.tgz",
                    "integrity": "sha512-/gDYp/UtU0eA1ys8bOs9J6a+E/KWIY+DZ+Q2WESNUA0jFRsJOc0SNUO6xJ5SGA1xueg3NL65W6s+NY5l9cunuw==",
                    "requires": {
                        "base64-js": "^1.0.2",
                        "ieee754": "^1.1.4"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The generated file is based on a very simple python program

```
data = { 'key0': 'a', 'key1': [ 1, 2, 3 ], 'key2': 'b', 'key3': [ { 'k0': 'random', 'k1': 'string', 'k2': 'to use', 'k3': 3.145 }, { 'k0': 'other', 'k1': 'values', 'k2': 'here', 'k3': 0.0001}] }
with open('test.bson', 'wb') as fp:
    encoded = bson.encode(data)
    fp.write(encoded)
```

The package being used for the python is `pymongo` (Version 3.10.1).

NOTE: I've updated the `data` dict. The first version worked fine when I used Dekel's solution. However, my actual data doesn't work. I modified it, and now it doesn't work with this error:

```
Uncaught Error: buffer length 199 must === bson size 253
  deserialize$1
```

I can load the file, however I cannot figure out the correct BSON calls to use in JS to get this to a Javascript object. I'm met with wrong type errors (needs a `Buffer`), transpilation errors, or exceptions.

My code looks like the following (it uses Dekel's `deserialize` in his answer).

```
import { deserialize } from 'bson'

let xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (xmlHttp.status == 200 && xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
        const buf = Buffer.from(xmlHttp.responseText, 'binary');
        const dat = deserialize(buf, {});
        console.log(dat);
    }
};
xmlHttp.open("GET", 'assets/test.bson');
xmlHttp.send();
```

If I didn't use the `{}` as the second argument to `deserialize`, it generates it results in

```
 TS2554: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1
```

I am using Webpack and Typescript for development.

It's not clear if the data is perhaps incorrect from the point of view of the JS BSON implementation or if I am calling the JS BSON incorrectly.

I can decode the file in python and `bsondump` also properly decodes the file.

I've created a GitHub repo which has more details as well as the test data. https://github.com/mobileben/test-bson-js

Some other details discovered.

- When converting to a `Buffer`, must include `binary` as the encoding, else it will not work right.
- This json (note it is represented as a python dict) `{"key3": [{"k0": "random", "k1": "string", "k2": "to use", "k3": 3.145}, {"k0": "other", "k1": "values", "k2": "here", "k3": 0.0001}]}` will cause the `Uncaught error` where the sizing doesn't match
- Float values, when using a dict that will not result in the `Uncaught error`, have the wrong value. If I use integer values, they are fine.

For the last item

```
{"key3": {"k9": "here", "k0": 1, "k1": 2, "k2": 3}}
```

Will work. It results in (on the JS-side)

```
{"key3":{"k9":"here","k0":1,"k1":2,"k2":3}}
```

However

```
{"key3": {"k9": "here", "k0": 0.1, "k1": 0.2, "k2": 0.3}}
```

Results in (on the JS side)

```
{"key3":{"k9":"here","k0":1.8745098039215684,"k1":1.8745098039215684,"k2":1.825}}
```

Running `bsondump` on the same file yields:

```
{"key3":{"k9":"here","k0":{"$numberDouble":"0.1"},"k1":{"$numberDouble":"0.2"},"k2":{"$numberDouble":"0.3"}}}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using `bson.encode` and not `bson.dumps`? seems like bson.encode is part of the mongo lib (and not the bson lib). Which of them are you using?

Comment: I'm using `bson.encode(data)` (code is above). The package I'm using is from `pymongo`. FWIW, I started with `bson` which uses `bson.dumps`. I moved to `pymongo` because I thought maybe it generated a slightly different output. They both resulted in the same file.

Comment: There was no mention to pymongo/mongodb so I just wanted to make sure there is no mistake here

Comment: Glad you checked. My bad, I updated the question with newer details and included `pymongo`. I did cite in the GitHub repo, but I should not expect people to read it there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the content of the file inside the `data` variable, you can use the BSON lib the following:

```
import { deserialize } from 'bson';
import data from '!!raw-loader!assets/test.bson'

console.log(deserialize(Buffer.from(data)))
```

If you are using the xmlhttprequest:

```
import { deserialize } from 'bson';

let xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (xmlHttp.status == 200 && xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
        console.log(deserialize(Buffer.from(xmlHttp.responseText)));
    }
};
xmlHttp.open("GET", 'assets/test.bson');
xmlHttp.send();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply as well as the example snippets. I've tried those permutations. With `deserialize` I get this error when transpiling:  TS2554: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1. I add a `{}`. Interestingly that worked. However if I actually use my real data (which is larger), I get faced with this which I've hit before: Uncaught Error: buffer length 15854 must === bson size 15869.

Comment: Try to `console.log` your data to see that it's actually what you expect there.

Comment: After the `deserialize`, right? I updated the code to what I'm using in my question. I'm double checking right now, but it appears what may "break" it right now is having an array of objects.

Comment: No, before... To see what's inside. I mostly wanna make sure it's the data and not a wrong import/require issue.

Comment: It is a `Uint8Array`, for example if I console it it becomes: `Uint8Array(65)`. I updated my question with the latest. The problem seems to be an array of objects that contains a mix of values which are strings and floats. I've also noticed that my simple float tests result in float values which are wrong.